# Trazer dados no Select com PHP

Tags: php, html

Boa noite...

Tenho um cadastro de pacientes. Preciso trazer  o médico que foi selecionado pelo componente SELECT. Para inclusão está ok. Mas caso eu buscar por um certo paciente para fazer alteração tenho trazer o médico selecionado e que também possa mostrar outros médicos no select caso eu deseje fazer alteração...
Estou programando em PHP...Como faço isso ?
Fico no aguardo

Rogério

Comment: tu quer mostrar todos os medicos no select e deixar selecionado o que o paciente esta relacionado isso?

Comment: Oi boa  tarde...Sim, isso mesmo..

Answer (score 0):

tu já teria pegado os dados do paciente, teria o código do medico que trata aquele pagiente, então é só ver para percorrer:
primeiro seleciona todos os medicos e faz um if aquele que for o medico tu coloca no começo

```
     echo "<select id=\"medico\">";
   $sql = " Select nomeMedico,id from medicos";
     $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
  while( $linha = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     // caso o codigo que estava no paciente for igual ao do medico atual tu marca
     if($codMed == $linha['id']){
        echo "<option value=\"$linha['id']\" selected=\"selected\">$linha['nomeMedico']</option> ";
     }else{
         echo "<option value=\"$linha['id']\">$linha['nomeMedico']</option> ";
     }

  }
```

Comment: Oi Gabriella, Seguindo as suas orientações, fiz assim: