# Trazer no select html o registro que foi salvo no banco

Tags: php, html, mysql

Bom dia
Alguém sabe me dizer como faço para trazer em um componente Select do html os registros que estão em PHP ? Na verdade, sei como trazer, mas como posso trazer somente o que foi salvo no banco e ao mesmo selecionar outros. Segue abaixo o codigo como estou fazendo.. Preciso trazer o médico que foi cadastrado mas ao mesmo tempo selecionar outros caso eu deseje alterar...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: oque é exibido na tela da forma que está agora?

Comment: Ele está trazendo todos os registros...

Comment: Lógico ele tem que trazer todos, mas ele não traz selecionado o que está salvo no banco..

Comment: esse `$tb_medico_id_medico["tb_medico_id_medico"]` seria oque esta salvo no banco?

Comment: Sim, é o que está salvo no banco...tb_medico_id_medico é o campo da tabela

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Trazer dados no Select com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365169/trazer-dados-no-select-com-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma, onde ele verifica o `id` e se for igual ele exibe um `selected`:

```
<?php

if(count($resultMedicoAll))
{
    foreach($resultMedicoAll as $res) { ?>
        <option value="<?=$res["id_medico"]?>" <?=($tb_medico_id_medico["tb_medico_id_medico"] == $res["id_medico"] ? "selected" : '')?>> <?=$res["nm_medico"]?> </option> 
<?php }
}

?>
```

Comment: Fiz o código que voce postou, mas não deu certo...

Comment: Opa, desculpa deu certo sim.. Esqueci de atualizar a página...Obrigadão...